# pdfjs mobile viewer centered pinch zoom

Tags: javascript, pinchzoom, pdf.js

I am using pdfjs mobile viewer (https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/mobile-viewer) in my web app. As far as I know pdf.js does not support pinch-zoom. I was able to add gesture recognition to this viewer, but my problem is that native zoom of pdf.js is not centered and zooms to left upper corner of the screen.

```js
pinchZoomIn: function pdfViewZoomIn(ticks) {
    let newScale = this.pdfViewer.currentScale;
    do {
        newScale = (newScale * PINCH_SCALE_DELTA).toFixed(2);
        newScale = Math.min(MAX_SCALE, newScale);
       } while (--ticks && newScale < MAX_SCALE);
    this.pdfViewer.currentScaleValue = newScale;
 }
```

Is there a way to reconfigure zoom to the center of the screen?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?